# Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *

Tags: c, cs50

This is a problem from the Harvard cs50 week 2, https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/2/substitution/.

It is giving me the error

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char* ;

It occurs in line 36 when I try to compile the program.
I am using the cs50.dev to run the vs code in browser. From here you can use the <cs50.h>
[image]

How can I fix it?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int len = strlen(pt);
    string ct;;
    string key = argv[1];
    int lenkey = strlen(key);
    if (lenkey < 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.");

    }
    else if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key");

    }
    else if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key");

    }
    string keyu;
    string keyl;
    // Key of uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(key[i]))
        {
            keyu = strcat(keyu, key[i]);
        }
        else if (islower(key[i]))
        {
            keyu = strcat(keyu, toupper(key[i]));
        }
    }
    // key of lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (islower(key[i]))
        {
            keyl = strcat(keyl, key[i]);
        }
        else if (isupper(key[i]))
        {
            keyl = strcat(keyl, toupper(key[i]));
        }
    }
    // create cyphertext
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (islower(pt[i]))
        {
            ct = strcat(ct, keyl[pt[i] - 97]);
        }
        else if (isupper(pt[i]))
        {
            ct = strcat(ct, keyu[pt[i] - 65]);
        }
        else
        {
            ct = strcat(ct, pt[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`strcat` expects the second argument to be another string, not a character](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcat).

Comment: Also it seems to me as if `string` is just a typedef for `char *` in your code... so all those operations you do with them are probably very wrong, like assigning them (and `ct` isn't even initialized). I just looked into this a bit and it seems CS50 tries to hide the fact that C doesn't actually have strings from you by defining this typedef for you, which I think is creating an incorrect mental model and is leading to all kinds of bugs and misunderstanding... I would recommend looking into another tutorial which teaches arrays and pointers first (and the dangers of working with "strings").

Comment: We don't have `<cs50.h>`. It's hard to reproduce your program. Do you know what's in that header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the good comments, the main issue for the error is that the "strcat" function is set up to concatenate one character array (string) to another character array (string).  In your code, it is attempting to concatenate a character to a character array.

Following is a refactored version of your program that builds the encrypted version of a word based upon an encryption key.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                        /* Usual declaration with input parameters              */
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char ct[30], pt[30], key[30], keyl[30], keyu[30];   /* Strings are character arrays                         */
    int len;
    //string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("plaintext: ");                              /* Common method to prompt for input                    */
    len = scanf("%s", pt);
    len = strlen(pt);

    //string ct;;
    //string key = argv[1];

    strcpy(key, argv[1]);                               /* Common string copy method                            */
    int lenkey = strlen(key);
    if (lenkey < 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.");
        return 2;
    }

    //string keyu;
    //string keyl;

    // Key of uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                        /* Simply store uppercase versions of the characters    */
    {
        keyu[i] = toupper(key[i]);
    }
    // key of lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)                        /* Simply store lowercase versions of the characters    */
    {
        keyl[i] = tolower(key[i]);
    }
    // create cyphertext
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (islower(pt[i]))
        {
            ct[i] = keyl[pt[i] - 97];
        }
        else if (isupper(pt[i]))
        {
            ct[i] = keyu[pt[i] - 65];
        }
        else
        {
            ct[i] = pt[i];
        }
    }

    printf("cypher text: %s\n", ct);

    return 0;
}
```

Some key points to this refactored code are:

- Since I do not have the "CS50" libraries and files installed on my system, code specifically utilizing functions and definitions within that context were commented out and generic definitions were used instead (e.g. instead of defining "string pt", pt is defined as a character array).
- Building uppercase and lowercase encryption keys did not really need to have lowercase or uppercase testing, so that made those "for loops" simpler.
- Instead of utilizing the "strcat" function, each character in the encrypted text is built character by character utilizing the key parameter.

Following were some tests of the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Substitution/bin/Release$ ./Substitution zyxwvytsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
plaintext: checkers
cypher text: xsvxpvih
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Substitution/bin/Release$ ./Substitution zyxwvytsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
plaintext: xsvxpvih
cypher text: checkers
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Substitution/bin/Release$ ./Substitution Hello there
Usage: ./substitution key
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Substitution/bin/Release$
```

In no way am I denigrating the "CS50" support library and files.  Utilize the functions as you see fit in your studies.  But as you evaluate code from other sources, you will probably see items such as character array definitions and other variable definitions more likely in this common format.  So you will want to also be comfortable with code built in that fashion.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion due to the <cs50.h>, but I have edited the post to account for this. Thanks a lot for the answer, I had already solved the problem and my code actually looked like yours, The reason I made separate keys for uppercase and lowercase was to test something(because i am beginner) .

Comment: I'm glad that you had solved the issue.  Your upper/lower case testing was not harmful, so it was not an issue.  Just wanted to point out that you would not need to do that.  That's okay.  We all have to start out as beginners.  To this day, I can often go back to previous code I've written and discover that I could simplify the code.  Enjoy the journey of learning.